# kubeflow deployment failed with knative domainmapping-webhook crashloopbackoff

Tags: crash, webhooks, kubeflow, knative-serving, domain-mapping

Just  install Charmed Kubeflow. Everything is ok but missing knative.

Keep crashing with log below

> {"severity":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-07-16T18:37:03.684598799Z","logger":"domainmapping-webhook","caller":"webhook/webhook.go:148","message":"failed
> to fetch
> secret","commit":"e82287d","knative.dev/pod":"domainmapping-webhook-7d79fb547-stf7v","error":"secret
> "domainmapping-webhook-certs" not
> found","stacktrace":"knative.dev/pkg/webhook.New.func2\n\tknative.dev/pkg@v0.0.0-20221011175852-714b7630a836/webhook/webhook.go:148\ncrypto/tls.(*Config).getCertificate\n\tcrypto/tls/common.go:1064\ncrypto/tls.(*serverHandshakeStateTLS13).pickCertificate\n\tcrypto/tls/handshake_server_tls13.go:363\ncrypto/tls.(*serverHandshakeStateTLS13).handshake\n\tcrypto/tls/handshake_server_tls13.go:55\ncrypto/tls.(*Conn).serverHandshake\n\tcrypto/tls/handshake_server.go:54\ncrypto/tls.(*Conn).handshakeContext\n\tcrypto/tls/conn.go:1460\ncrypto/tls.(*Conn).HandshakeContext\n\tcrypto/tls/conn.go:1403\nnet/http.(*conn).serve\n\tnet/http/server.go:1848"}
> 2023/07/16 18:37:03 http: TLS handshake error from
> 172.18.188.137:60698: tls: no certificates configured

not even where to start